# Cant post Article with image which is already uploaded to Linkedin

Tags: file-upload, article

I want to post a Article with a image. I got to know through "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/vector-asset-api?tabs=http" link, How to upload images to linkedin through Api, I followed the same process made a post to "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/assets?action=registerUpload" for which i got uploadUrl and asset in response,

I made a put request to uploadUrl, attaching a image in binary format and I got the Status as 201 Created,

I queried to check the status of image through get request to "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/assets/{asset}" and I got response as id,created,mediaTypeFamily,lastModified,status which says that image is uploaded to linkedin

but when I try to use "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares" to post a Article with {"entity":"urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:{asset}"} in body, I get a error

{
"message": "com.linkedin.content.common.ResponseException: One or more of the assets is not owned by the author. All assets must be owned by the author",
"status": 400
}

couldn't figure what is the issue ?

Comment: => Issue was with input parameters in 1st upload api where there was a typo in owner name but the API created the upload url without error as that user was not existing and when we tried to share the image in post where owner was correct, API saw mismatch in owner of upload url and share owner and gave error "One or more of the assets is not owned by the author. All assets must be owned by the author". i.e the owner who is trying to share is owned by different owner

Comment: The question tags are too generic, about which technology are you asking about?